# "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Database" when try to connect with Database from TypeORM CLI while basically connection is fine

Tags: node.js, docker, typeorm

Relevant part of the **docker-compose.yaml**:

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:

  Database:

    image: postgres
    container_name: Example-Local-Database
    ports:
      - "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}"

    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"

    volumes:
      - DatabaseData:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  # ...

volumes:
  DatabaseData:
    name: Example-Local-DatabaseData
    driver: local
```

**ENV variables** (calm down, no sensitive information to steal, just default settings for the local development mode):

```
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_PASSWORD=pass1234
```

**DataSource** configuration:

```
{
    type: "postgres",
    host: "Database",
    port: 5432,
    username: "postgres",
    password: "pass1234",
    entities: [ MemberModel ]
}
```

The connection from IntelliJ IDEA is fine:

[image]

Same for my NestJS application.

However, the `typeorm` CLI could not connect with this database.
For example, the command `typeorm migration:generate test/test2 -- -d typeorm-cli.config.ts`
causes the error:

```
Error during migration generation:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Database
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'Database'
}
```

I have checked the [trying to connect typeorm with mysql container in docker-compose but i get this error Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74081936/trying-to-connect-typeorm-with-mysql-container-in-docker-compose-but-i-get-this) topics: in my case, the **host** refers to **Database** the service name mentioned in **docker-compose.yaml**.

Answer (score 2):

You exposed ports to host so you should use `localhost` as db_host to connect.
If you trying to connect from another container you should use `host.docker.internal` as db_host to connect.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your IntelliJ screenshot, you're using `localhost` as the host name.

In your code, you use `Database` which only works on the Docker network. Not from the host.

Change your code to use `localhost` as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Previously, it was `localhost` in my code. Why I changed it is the ECONNREFUSED error [caused by the loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33363660/4818123). How to avoid this error will come back?