# ENOTFOUND vs. ECONNREFUSED: how to setup the Data Source such as make it available from both inside and outside of Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker

If we'll set the `host` setting to `localhost` as below

```
import type { PostgresConnectionOptions } from "typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions";

export default function generateTypeORM_Configuration(): PostgresConnectionOptions {
  return {
    type: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    username: "postgres",
    password: "pass1234",
    entities: []
  };
}
```

we could deal with

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.01:5432
```

because of the [loopback adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface). This problem has been discussed in [ECONNREFUSED for Postgres on nodeJS with dockers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357567/econnrefused-for-postgres-on-nodejs-with-dockers) topics.

However if to replace the `localhost` with Docker service name:

```js
{
    type: "postgres",
    host: "Database",
    port: 5432,
    username: "postgres",
    password: "pass1234",
    entities: [ MemberModel ]
}
```

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:

  Database:

    image: postgres
    container_name: Example-Local-Database
    ports:
      - "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}"

    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"

    volumes:
      - DatabaseData:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  # ...

volumes:
  DatabaseData:
    name: Example-Local-DatabaseData
    driver: local
```

we'll face with

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Database
```

error if try to run the migration. In the topics ["getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Database" when try to connect with Database from TypeORM CLI while basically connection is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75634661/getaddrinfo-enotfound-database-when-try-to-connect-with-database-from-typeorm/75634755#75634755) I have been told to set `host` to `localhost` - back to square one. Of course I have tried to comment about it in this topics before create new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're setting up your database configuration in code, it should be straightforward to use an environment variable there.  A Compose `environment:` block can then set its value to a Compose-specific value.  I like to set these up so that, if the environment variable isn't set, it uses a reasonable developer-friendly default.

So you might set for example

```js
export default function generateTypeORM_Configuration(): PostgresConnectionOptions {
  return {
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.DB_HOST || "localhost",
    ...
  }
}
```

If you just run this locally, `$DB_HOST` won't be set and it will fall back to `localhost`.  In Compose you need to set that environment variable

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      DB_HOST: database
  database:
    image: postgres
```

This same approach will work in other environments.  Imagine using a hosted Amazon RDS database in production, for example; you'd just need to plug in the database's host name as an environment variable and not need to actually change your application at all to use that.